# How to set Collation in Flyway?

Tags: mysql, sql, flyway

I tried to create a table with collation, as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE cuisines (
    id          VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    enName      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    frName      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    spotlight   BOOLEAN     NOT NULL,
    enabled     BOOLEAN     NOT NULL,
    emojis      VARCHAR(40),
    image_url   VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

However, Flyway says that there is a syntax error, as shown below.

```
[ERROR] Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE CUISINES (
[ERROR]     ID          VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
[ERROR]     ENNAME      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
[ERROR]     FRNAME      VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
[ERROR]     SPOTLIGHT   BOOLEAN     NOT NULL,
[ERROR]     ENABLED     BOOLEAN     NOT NULL,
[ERROR]     EMOJIS      VARCHAR(40),
[ERROR]     IMAGE_URL   VARCHAR(255),
[ERROR]     PRIMARY KEY (ID)
[ERROR] ) DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8MB4 COLLATE[*] UTF8MB4_UNICODE_CI ";
```

Could someone please teach me how to set collation in Flyway?

Thank you!

Comment: Which versions of Flyway, MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried that script with MySQL 8.0.11 and Flyway 7.1, and the migration works. I believe it is not a Flyway error per se, it's coming from the database - which suggests the SQL is wrong for your version of MySQL. The `[*]` in the error message is odd... that wasn't in your script at any stage?

Comment: No, that `*` is not a part of my code. I guess it is to indicate where the problem is. In this case, it is `COLLATE`.